# How to display google results on same page without sending form to google itself

Tags: jquery, html, search

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="MySearch">
<input type="submit" value="MySearch">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This sends page to google. I would like to stay on my page and display only the list results from google.

Comment: Use an `iFrame` or use a [GOOGLE SEARCH API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Comment: in this case I cannot use an iFrame

Answer (score 0):

It's Possible to use Google Search API, you can find a code snippet below and learn more about how this work https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/introduction there.

Good luck

```
function getGoogleSearchResults(q) {

// Get the API key from Google's developer console
// Get the CSE ID from google.com/cse

var api = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" +
    KEY + "&cx=" + CSE + "&q=" + encodeURIComponent(q);

try {

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, {
        muteHttpExceptions: true
    });

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        var content = JSON.parse(response);

        // Did the search return any results?
        if (content.searchInformation.totalResults > 0) {

            var count = content.items.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                // Save the page title, description and hyperlink
                Logger.log(content.items[i].title);
                Logger.log(content.items[i].snippet);
                Logger.log(content.items[i].link);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: could you give an example using the function?